# How to edit the About page on Xcode's "Cocoa Application" template

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I created an application using Xcode 4.5's Cocoa Application template. I see that there are a whole bunch of menus that I don't need which I removed. The one I would like to keep is the About page but I can't find where it is taking its data from.

(I've only done a bunch of iOS apps and this is my first desktop app with Cocoa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `Credits.rtf` file automatically created by XCode. You can find it in the group `Supporting Files`.

If you want to edit the Copyright information you need to change the `NSHumanReadableCopyright` key in the `<YouAppName>Info.plist` file of your application.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that file there! One question though, the copyright line doesn't seem to be there. Where can I edit it?

Comment: I the Info.plist file for your project

Comment: Specifically you need to change the `NSHumanReadableCopyright` key

Comment: Is there a way to use automatic year variable in the Info.plist? Or how to make a ${CURRENT_YEAR} variable that could be used there?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the .plist file, Copyright (human-readable) item.