# Custom build variables in Xcode

Tags: xcode, variables, build

I have a Mac application built with Xcode and in its `Info.plist` file there's the "human readable" copyright field as discussed / answered e. g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793187/how-to-edit-the-about-page-on-xcodes-cocoa-application-template)

The problem is that I notoriously forget to update the copyright "years" there and would like to use a variable that would insert current year during build process, similar to all other variables used in that file. Apple doesn't seem to provide anything date related. Does anyone know how I could create such a variable and where?

Edit: I know that I can add a custom build phase and update content of the file this way but I would very much prefer to be able to define a variable, which would then be used the same way other variables are used inside `Info.plist` file

Comment: Since it only needs to be updated once a year, set a reminder in the Reminders app to update Info.plist in your project on January 1st every year. Otherwise you would need to add a custom build script in Build Phases. Some simple shell script could be written to update Info.plist with the copyright string containing the current year.

Comment: Well, I know that I can add custom build phase and "manually" update file content this way but I hoped for a way to define my variable(s), which would be then used during build. That would come in handy for other situations too